# How to define HTTP method and status code of Login and Logout?

Tags: api, rest, http-status-codes, http-method

I give an common user login/logout example about discussing `HTTP method` and `status code`. I hope It can help people to understand easily.

---

Traditional no restful api design:

> When user login/logout a website, it's sure to access backend service by HTTP request of `POST` method.

It's beyond question.

---

But if I follow restful api design pattern, is still it be designed?

My thought is:

- Login

> `Login` will generate a token key when user login. I think it's a creation action for database because generating a token key, so should it return `201 Created` status code?

- Logout

> Relatively, `Logout` will delete the token key when user send his token and do logout. I think it's a deletion action for db because deleting the token key, so should it return `204 No content` status code?

Although I think it maybe fits in with HTTP method meaning, if I will offer or share this  API design, does it make other developer confuse?

I don't know this idea is or isn't good. I want to listen your opinion.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that the scenario that you describe would be confusing to developers. In my experience, it's rare that you would have special handling around a 200, a 201, or a 204 whereas the typical case is `code >= 200 && code < 300`. Your logic is not unsound. If you're returning a token, a `201` would be reasonable and a `204` if you're not returning any content.

However, generating a token is really a side-effect of you logging in. `POST /login` is not creating a `login` resource like `POST /items` would be creating an `item`, and API tokens are not typical resources. For that reason, a `200 OK` would be more appropriate since you're really just giving the user permission to move forward to protected resources, albeit by creating a token. If you look around for authentication examples, it seems that sending a `200` or redirecting the user are the typical solutions.

Comment: These lines **generating a token is really a side-effect of you logging in**  standout - reminding of Separation of Concern for API design.

Answer (score 0):

Both `login` and `logout` should be POST because GET may get cached under some circumstances.
On logout success server may set response status 302 redirect and header `location: url_to_visit_after_logout`